Server not retrieving a value to a client in a server-client project in C#
I'm currently working on a client-server project in C# but is not working as expected. I proceed to explain.
On the server side, I have this class:
public class MensajeSocket<T>
{
    public string Metodo {  get; set; }
    public T Entidad { get; set; }
}

When I configure the server, I initialize the server like this:
TcpListener tcpListener;
Thread subprocesoEscuchaClientes;
EscribirEnTextboxDelegado modificarTextotxtBitacora;
ModoficarListBoxDelegado modificarListBoxClientes;
RegistrarPedidoArticulos NuevoPedido;

string NombreCliente = string.Empty;
string PrimerApellido = string.Empty;
string SegundoApellido = string.Empty;

bool servidorIniciado;

public Ventana_Servidor()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NuevoPedido = new RegistrarPedidoArticulos();
    btnDetener.Enabled = false;
}

private delegate void EscribirEnTextboxDelegado(string texto);
private delegate void ModoficarListBoxDelegado(string texto, bool agregar);

private void btnIniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IPAddress local = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    tcpListener = new TcpListener(local, 13200);
    servidorIniciado = true;

    subprocesoEscuchaClientes = new Thread(new ThreadStart(EscucharClientes));
    subprocesoEscuchaClientes.Start();
    subprocesoEscuchaClientes.IsBackground = true;
    EtiquetaConexion.Text = "Escuchando clientes... en (127.0.0.1, 13200)";
    btnIniciar.Enabled = false;
    btnDetener.Enabled = true;
    BitacoraConexiones.Text = "Servidor iniciado... en (127.0.0.1, 13200)";
    BitacoraConexiones.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
}

private void EscucharClientes()
{
    tcpListener.Start();

    try
    {
        while (servidorIniciado)
        {
            TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(() => ManejarCliente(client));
            clientThread.Start();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return;
    }
}

private void ManejarCliente(object cliente)
{
    TcpClient tcCliente = (TcpClient)cliente;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tcCliente.GetStream());
    StreamWriter servidorStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(tcCliente.GetStream());

    while (servidorIniciado)
    {
        try
        {
            /*Esta sección se bloquea hasta que el cliente envíe un mensaje*/
            var mensaje = reader.ReadLine();
            MensajeSocket<object> mensajeRecibido = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MensajeSocket<object>>(mensaje);
            SeleccionarMetodo(mensajeRecibido.Metodo, mensaje, ref servidorStreamWriter);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { 
            break;
        }
    }
    tcCliente.Close();
}

public void SeleccionarMetodo(string FuncionSolicitada, string NombreFuncion, ref StreamWriter servidorStreamWriter)
{
    try
    {
        switch (FuncionSolicitada)
        {
            case "ValidarCliente":
                MensajeSocket<string> mensajeValidarCliente = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MensajeSocket<string>>(NombreFuncion);
                bool clientevalido = ValidarCliente(mensajeValidarCliente.Entidad);
                string respuesta = clientevalido ? "true" : "false";
                servidorStreamWriter.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(respuesta));
                servidorStreamWriter.Flush();
                break;
            default:
                break;
                }
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException ex) 
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Error de comunicación. El mensaje recibido está vacío");
       Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }
}

private bool ValidarCliente(string IDCliente)
{
    try
    {
        RegistrarClientes RegistroClientes = new RegistrarClientes();
        List<Cliente> ClientesActuales = RegistroClientes.Consultar();

        for (int i = 0; i < ClientesActuales.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ClientesActuales[i].IDCliente.Equals(IDCliente))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error. Favor contactar al administrador");
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    return false;
}

Obviously, within the switch selector there are other options. However, the one that I put is the one that's currently giving me issues.
That was from the side of the server. On the client side, I have the following:
private static IPAddress ipServidor;
private static TcpClient cliente;
private static IPEndPoint serverEndPoint;
private static StreamWriter clienteStreamWriter;
private static StreamReader clienteStreamReader;

public static string NombreCliente = string.Empty;
public static string PrimerApellido = string.Empty;
public static string SegundoApellido = string.Empty;
public static string idCliente = string.Empty;

public static bool ValidarCliente(string IDCliente)
{
    bool cliente_validado = false;

    try
    {
        MensajeSocket<string> mensajeValidarCliente = new MensajeSocket<string> { Metodo = "ValidarCliente", Entidad = IDCliente };
        clienteStreamReader = new StreamReader(cliente.GetStream());
        clienteStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(cliente.GetStream());
        clienteStreamWriter.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mensajeValidarCliente));
        clienteStreamWriter.Flush();

        var mensaje = clienteStreamReader.ReadLine();

        cliente_validado = mensaje.Equals("true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No se pudo conectar al servidor");
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No se pudo conectar al servidor");
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    return cliente_validado;
}

That's all the code I think is necessary. Now, I'll proceed to explain. On the client site of the project, the user must provide its ID in a Windows Forms window. Then, the method ValidarCliente takes that ID and send it over the the server, so it can look for it on a database.
When I run both applications, I use an existing ID, just to make sure the logic works. However, once I enter the ID, neither client or server provides an output or an answer.
The method ValidarCliente takes a string and should provide a boolean output. However, for some reason, the system was not able to process it. It said that since MensajeSocket.Entidad was already a string, it cannot be converted to bool, which makes total sense.
I revised with Gemini, the AI from Google, and it suggested to send the response back to the client as string and convert it on that site to boolean but is not working either.
I also put those try catch sections because the IDE, Visual Studio Community, says there's a chance that some arguments, like mensajeValidarCliente, could be null.

Implementing your own tcp server when a couple of clicks will get you a brand new rest API project complete with a swagger UI (a webpage client that automatically populates with all the different commands you care to put in your controllers) for testing? I mean, if you're looking for something more low level, lightweight than http etc how about a signal R server/client pairing? The only time I'd roll my own tcp server these days would be to match a custom protocol supported by a client I couldn't change. And even then I'd consider if it would be faster to replace the client than reverse it
